# Solving Exact Cover by Three Products in Python

Tags: python, math-expression-eval, set

I'm a computer-science hobbyist and found an NP-complete problem that is similar to both [subset-product](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7907/is-the-subset-product-problem-np-complete) and [Exact Cover by 3-sets](https://npcomplete.owu.edu/2014/06/10/exact-cover-by-3-sets/).

Here is a Reduction of Exact-Cover into my problem. I am multiplying all integers in sets of C.

```
Input prior to reduction
s:  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
c:  [[5, 2, 1], [6, 4, 3]]
Output after reduction
s : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
c : [10, 72]
Integers needed for True subset-product
[[5, 2, 1], [6, 4, 3]]
```

### Algorithm

```py
import itertools
from itertools import combinations
from itertools import permutations
import operator
from operator import mul
from functools import reduce

s = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
c = 10,72


# Preparing all possible
# three-element sets

find_X_thr_covers=[];
for jj in permutations((s), 3):
    if len(jj) == len(set(jj)):
        # I will "remember" multiplied sets in c for later use.
        if reduce(mul, jj) in c:
            find_X_thr_covers.append(jj)


# Here, I will use len(s)//3 combinations
# for a special case of the Exact Cover
# problem by 3-sets.

solutions = []
solutions_two = []
for jj in combinations(find_X_thr_covers, len(s)//3):
    # Here I will verify that every possible combination
    # is indeed a true solution.
    jj_flat = [item for sub in jj for item in sub]
    jj_set = set(jj_flat)
    if set(s) == jj_set and len(jj_set) == len(jj_flat):
        solution = list(jj)
        # I will use a for loop to multiply all elements in
        # the Exact Three Cover solutions.
        for a in range(0, len(solution)):
            solution[a] = reduce(mul, solution[a])
            if a == len(solution) - 1:
                solutions.append(solution)
                solutions_two = jj
                break

# removing repeating sets
solutions =[solutions[x] for x in range(len(solutions)) if not(solutions[x] in solutions[:x])]

print(solutions)
print(solutions_two)
print('Found Exact Three Product Cover')
```

### Output

```
[[10, 72], [72, 10]]
((5, 2, 1), (6, 4, 3))
Found Exact Three Product Cover
```

### Questions

Is using fixed permutations of 3 a bad way to solve this problem?

What's the slowest parts of my Python script and how do I improve execution speed with [Algorithm X](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exact-cover-problem-algorithm-x-set-1/)?

The Algorithm X isn't necessary to be provided as a solution but should only be explained if possible in a pythonic manner. I'm fine with an answer that only explains the problems with my code.

Comment: Just found out that if I limit input length to the 31 facrors of 720 it woul speed up algorithim?

Comment: Just check that all values in C are a factor of the total product of s. And remove repeating values. Thus the maximum possible length of c would be 31 factora.